# Custom Repo without extends error: No repository for was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

When I use Custom Repository class without any extension then I run into the error: *No repository for "MasterDataRepo" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?*

```js
@EntityRepository()
export class MasterDataRepo {

  constructor(private manager: EntityManager) {
  }

  getDriveryByTerminal(terminalCode: string):Promise<Driver> {
    return this.manager.findOne(Driver, { terminalCode });
  }
}
```

The app works fine if I create repository class after extending `Repository<Entity>`

```js
@EntityRepository(Driver)
export class MasterDataRepo extends Repository<Driver> {

    getDriveryByTerminal(terminalCode: string):Promise<Driver> {
      return this.manager.findOne(Driver, { terminalCode });
    }
}
```

My `MasterDataModule` is:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MasterDataController } from './MasterData.controller';
import { MasterDataService } from './masterData.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { MasterDataRepo } from './MasterData.Repo';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([MasterDataRepo])
  ],
  controllers: [MasterDataController],
  providers: [MasterDataService],
})
export class MasterDataModule {}
```

and `AppModule` is:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksModule } from './tasks/tasks.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { typeOrmConfig } from './config/typeorm.config';
import { MasterDataModule } from './masterData/MasterData.module';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig),
    TasksModule,
    MasterDataModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private connection: Connection) {}
}
```

Comment: I see one similar question: https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/issues/92 But can not make out the solution from here.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, @yash. I could find a workaround.  Defined the repo as injecatable

```js
@Injectable()
@EntityRepository()
export class MasterDataRepo {

    constructor(private manager: EntityManager) {
    }

    getDriveryByTerminal(terminalCode: string):Promise<Driver> {
        return this.manager.findOne(Driver, { terminalCode });
    }
}
```

and the service as

```js
@Injectable()
export class MasterDataService {
  constructor(
    private masterDataRepo: MasterDataRepo,
  ) {}
}
```

Do you see any concerns?

Answer (score 2):

```js
TypeOrmModule.forFeature([MasterDataRepo])
```

`TypeOrmModule.forFeature` accepts array of `Entities` and your `MasterDataRepo` is not an entity.

But when you use `EntityRepository` decorator with the `User` entity, it will add your `User` entity to the available `entities` list(which will be applied to the database connection).
Also extending the `Repository` class will make your `MasterDataRepo` as an extended version of an `Entity`.

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/906d97fc8dbf1dba8f4e579a4f5bfead83af36ab/src/decorator/EntityRepository.ts

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/906d97fc8dbf1dba8f4e579a4f5bfead83af36ab/src/repository/Repository.ts

**Note:**

There are two solutions:

1. Nestjs already provides `@nestjs/typeorm` module and you can inject a repository for an entity easily in your service.

For example:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>
  ) {}
  ...
}
```

You can check the documentation here - https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database

2. You can just use `Active Record` pattern that doesn't require a repository.
   What you need to do is just to make your entities extend `BaseEntity` of typeorm.

For example:

```js
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {} // <- BaseEntity

...

const user = await User.find({}) // You just use the User class for executing a query.
user.name = 'something';
await user.save();
```

Comment: that's great  @Rajeev

Answer (score 0):

For those using TypeORM and who had the Injection configured correctly but still running into the error:

In my case, the issue was that my @Entity was not registered in the Postgres `TypeOrmModuleOptions` (more precisely the `entity` array of the `BaseConnectionOptions`, cf [their git repo](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/51b2a63d91d4e6a935e83f47fb958f4867e82e9c/src/connection/BaseConnectionOptions.ts#L28) ). Those options allow to configure Nest's `TypeOrmModule`

Hope this helps someone else coming to this thread